# UINavigation Bar at wrong position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I started designing an app for iPhone 5 (4-inch screen) and decided to adjust it later for 3,5 inch screens, but I encountered a really strange problem...

The UINavigationBar is placed correctly (4-inch):

http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/yrwzr498_png.htm

The UINavigationBar is placed on the bottom (3.5-inch):
http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3168/6dmsf238_png.htm

(Auto-Layout is turned off by the way)

Please help me!

Comment: Please could you say what the really strange problem is? :-)

Comment: elaborate more about the issue?

Comment: seems like my screenshots were not added...

Comment: as you can see the position of the UINavigationBar is perfect: [link](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/yrwzr498_png.htm) I created a seperate Storyboard for the 3,5 inch screen devices but there occurs this problem: [link](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/hvu6apr2_png.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've hinted at the answer yourself: auto layout. Without more information its difficult to provide and answer...

But, auto layout and/or autoResizingMasks are there to let your views and UI objects respond dynamically to size changes. If you have a layout problem between 4" screen and 3.5" screen, you probably need to be using auto layout.

Comment: as you can see the position of the UINavigationBar is perfect: [link](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/yrwzr498_png.htm) I created a seperate Storyboard for the 3,5 inch screen devices but there occurs this problem: [link](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/hvu6apr2_png.htm)